# Testing apple push notification service

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

i tried "easy-ASPN" http://www.easyapns.com on my server..

this is the php code for connecting apple server:

```
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'apns.pem');
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $error, $errorString, 100, (STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT), $ctx);
```

i am ensure that openssl is enabled in php configuration..

server administrator told me thad he opened ports: 2196, 2196

but this php code always returns:

```
Failed to connect to APNS: 110 Connection timed out.
```

i tried to test the connection to apple server from the shell,

i have wrote:

```
telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
```

but it returned:

```
-bash: telnet: command not found
```

i am really don't know how to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

I see two things that could be causing your problem.  First you need to send your passphrase:

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'your_passphrase');
```

Also, you should be hitting the feedback URL:

```
ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196
```

(the sandbox part of the URL is for dev, remove it if you are hitting your prod instance)

Hope that helps.

Comment: What is "your_passphrase"? Where does this come from? When I created the PEM files I left the password blank ... is that what this passphrase is supposed to be, or is it something else? Thanks

Comment: Leave it blank, like ''